# Если такой файл есть, то создать файл с другим производным именем

Tags: c#

Сделал так:

```
string Path = @"C:\\data\i1.txt";

if(File.Exists(Path))
{
     Path = @"C:\\data\***например "i+1.txt"***
}
```

Как это сделать? Например первый файл: i1.txt, а остальные были i2, i3, i4... и т.д 
Или может предложите более лучший вариант?

**UPDATE**

Или же задать созданному файлу - название textbox. У меня при нажатии на кнопку создается новый текстбокс. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии одновременно создавался и текстовый файл(это я могу) с названием самого текстбокса(это как раз таки не умею)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Более лучший вариант":

```
System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()
System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName()
```

P.S.: Некоторым это покажется странным, но в системе может не оказаться диска с меткой **C:**

**UPDATE#1:**

> пытаюсь сейчас сделать так:
>
> string Path = @"C:\data\" + textBox1.Name + ".txt";
>
> только вот как сделать типа:
>
> this.Textbox.Name
>
> а не textBox1.Name.
>
> Ну чтобы в общем виде приписать.

Я бы отнаследовался от TextBox, добавив в него такое свойство:

```
public string CacheFileName
{
    get 
    { 
        return String.Format("cache_{0}.txt", Name); 
    }
}
```

Comment: >> и как пользоваться ею, можешь сказать?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx

>> я бы хотел такой вариант, который я описал выше

Он изначально представляет из себя плохую идею.

Comment: >> Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии одновременно создавался и текстовый файл(это я могу) с названием самого текстбокса(это как раз таки не умею)

А в чем проблема? В получении имени текстбокса? Так оно доступно из свойства Control.Name

Comment: Ну так припиши. Что мешает?

Comment: пытаюсь сейчас сделать так: 

     string Path = @"C:\\data\" + textBox1.Name + ".txt";

только вот как сделать типа: 

     this.Textbox.Name

а не textBox1.Name. Ну чтобы в общем виде приписать. До этого я так написал(сверху):

    this.Controls.Add(new TextBox()
    {
         Location = new Point(x, y), Multiline = true, Width = 527, Height = 30
    }
    );

Comment: Обновил ответ.